# How associate order with a current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, shopping-cart

I'm building a store that has items and orders for each user. 
Right now I want to associate each order with a current_user. That is, the one that is making an order.
I figured how to associate models but I can't figure out what to write that will save user_id to order model upon the creation of an order. I'm using standard Devise engine.

These are my models:

Order.rb

```
 belongs_to :order_status
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :order_items
  before_create :set_order_status
  before_save :update_subtotal

  def subtotal
    order_items.collect { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) : 0 }.sum
  end
private
  def set_order_status
    self.order_status_id = 1
  end

  def update_subtotal
    self[:subtotal] = subtotal
  end
end
```

order_item.rb

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :order

  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validate :product_present
  validate :order_present

  before_save :finalize

  def unit_price
    if persisted?
      self[:unit_price]
    else
      product.price
    end
  end

  def total_price
    unit_price * quantity
  end

private
  def product_present
    if product.nil?
      errors.add(:product, "is not valid or is not active.")
    end
  end

  def order_present
    if order.nil?
      errors.add(:order, "is not a valid order.")
    end
  end

  def finalize
    self[:unit_price] = unit_price
    self[:total_price] = quantity * self[:unit_price]
  end
end
```

And in the user.rb I have: `has_one :order`

This is my OrderItemsController:

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
    @order.save
    session[:order_id] = @order.id
  end

  def update
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.update_attributes(order_item_params)
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end

  def destroy
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.destroy
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end
private
  def order_item_params
    params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity, :product_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple ways to go about associating a user with an order. A user should have many orders. First, have you written a migration to add a `user_id` column to your orders table? Create one by reference: `rails g migration AddUserToOrder user:references`

Then update your permitted params for order to permit `user_id`.

From there you have the option of doing a few things...you could set the `user_id` in the create action of your orders controller before saving. (related but not your Q--you're going to need an order_id for an order_item, no?) Alternatively, you could pass the user_id in your form via a hidden field.

Either of those will associate it for you.

Comment: Ok I permitted the params but what exactly should I write in create action to set user_id? As I'm already stating params in create action: @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params) so it confuses me..

Comment: Are you trying to save it on order or on order_items?

Comment: You have the reference, too, right? user_id shows up in your schema.rb file? `@order.user_id = current_user.id` before `@order.save` should take care of it. If that doesn't do it...update your question with the params hash from the stack trace.

Comment: @MarkoI. No problem. Accept answer?

Comment: @toddemetheny just did :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign it like this:

```
current_user.order = @order
current_user.save
```

If you want a user to has_many orders down the line, it would be:

```
current_user.orders << @order
```